# Can gcd separate primes from composite numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures

Let $x_i=i+1, 1\le i \le n$, $y_i = +1,$ if $x_i$ is prime, $-1$ otherwise.

**Conjecture**:
Then (?) there exists $b,c_i \in \mathbb{R}, 1 \le i \le n$ such that for all $j=1,\ldots,n$:

$$y_j = \text{ sgn }\left(\left[\sum_{i=1}^n c_iy_i\gcd( x_i,  x_j)\right] - b\right)$$

Motivation for asking this question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349589/are-primes-linearly-separable

Thanks for your help!

this question has been answered at mo.

Comment: This criterion will be of theoretical interest only. Upto which limit did you check it ?

Comment: @Peter: Up to $n=500$. Why are so sure, that this will be only of theoretical interest? ( I am not saying that it may be of practiacal interest, but I am neither including nor excluding it.)

Comment: This test will be much slower than the known primality tests, even if we want to be absolutely sure whether the number is prime.

Comment: I did not say to use it as a primality test... although currently I am thinking in this direction on maybe how to modify this test ...